# What are the key differences between cellular neural network and convolutional neural network?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, comparison, cellular-neural-networks

What are the key differences between [cellular neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_neural_network) and [convolutional neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network) in terms of working principle, implementation, potential performance, and applicability?